# SQLiteDatabase insert() method always return -1

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database which is **Shelter.db**, in contains a table called "**Pets**": 
it's schema is

```
CREATE TABLE pets (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT NOT NUL, breed TEXT NOT NUL, gender INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, weight INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);
```

I am trying to add new row using insert function. This function must return id of this adding. But when I check this from debugger, I see that it return -1.

Here are the **"SQLiteOpenHelper.cs"**

**PetDbHelper.cs**

```
public class PetDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "shelter.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public PetDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        /*CREATE TABLE pets (_id INTEGER, name TEXT, breed TEXT, gender INTEGER, weight INTEGER);*/

        // Create a String that contains the SQL statement to create the pets table
        String SQL_CREATE_PETS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + PetEntry.TABLE_NAME + "("
                + PetEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME + "TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_BREED + "TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_GENDER + "INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, "
                + PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_WEIGHT + "INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);" ;

        // Execute the SQL statement
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_PETS_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

and here are where i am trying to insert new row

```
private void insertPet() {
 PetDbHelper mDbHelper = new PetDbHelper(this);

// Gets the database in write mode
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME, "Toto");
    values.put(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_BREED, "Terrier");
    values.put(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_GENDER, PetEntry.GENDER_MALE);
    values.put(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_WEIGHT, 7);

    try {
        long newRowId = db.insert(PetEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Exception","SQLException"+String.valueOf(e.getMessage()));
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

**every time it return -1 !!!!!!!!**

Comment: Does it throw the exception? If so, what is the exception? Maybe you are calling your `insertPet()` from the main thread and it throws an error.

Comment: All these lines: `+ PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME + "TEXT NOT NULL, "                + PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_BREED + "TEXT NOT NULL, " +PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_GENDER + "INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, "               + PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_WEIGHT + "INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);" ;` need a space like: `" TEXT.......` before the type of the column. Then uninstall the app and rerun.

Comment: thanks . really appreciate your help .. it works -->> the problem was in " Spaces " in the Sql Create query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed your `CREATE TABLE` statement. You're missing spaces between the column names and the data types:

```
  private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES = "CREATE TABLE " +
      PetEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
      PetEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
      PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
      PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_BREED + " TEXT, " +
      PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_GENDER + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
      PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_WEIGHT + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);";
```

Comment: the problem was in " Spaces " in the Sql Create query